# Проблема со смещением в шифре цезаря

Tags: python, строки, unicode

Стандартный шифр Цезаря.
Проблема в расчетной формуле, если задано смещение больше длины алфавита.
Ожидаю, что при смещении 1, буква А станет Б, а при смещении 34 буква Я станет А.
Не пойму что напутал в цифрах.

```
eng_lower_alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
eng_upper_alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
rus_lower_alphabet = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
rus_upper_alphabet = "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
symbol = [" ", ",", ".", "!", "?"]

def shift(i, offset):
    if i.isalpha():
        if i in eng_lower_alphabet:
            print(eng_lower_alphabet[(ord(i) + (offset % 26)) - 97])
        if i in rus_lower_alphabet:
            print(rus_lower_alphabet[(ord(i) + (offset % 33)) - 1072])
        if i in eng_upper_alphabet:
            print(eng_upper_alphabet[(ord(i) + (offset % 26)) - 65])
        if i in rus_upper_alphabet:
            print(rus_upper_alphabet[(ord(i) + (offset % 33)) - 1040])
        
print("Введите букву")
phrase = input()
shift(phrase, 1088)
```

Ошибка:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-1f3e9ddd2432> in <module>
     18 print("Введите букву")
     19 phrase = input()
---> 20 shift(phrase, 1088)
     21 
     22 

<ipython-input-99-1f3e9ddd2432> in shift(i, offset)
     10             print(eng_lower_alphabet[(ord(i) + (offset % 26)) - 97])
     11         if i in rus_lower_alphabet:
---> 12             print(rus_lower_alphabet[(ord(i) + (offset % 33)) - 1072])
     13         if i in eng_upper_alphabet:
     14             print(eng_upper_alphabet[(ord(i) + (offset % 26)) - 65])

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас в `rus_lower_alphabet` и `rus_upper_alphabet` всего 32 буквы, поэтому надо брать остаток от деления на 32, а не на 33, как у вас.

```
offset % 33 --> offset % 32
```

`1088 % 33 = 32`, поэтому индекс выходит за границу списка. Диапазон корректных индексов для списка из 32 элементов: `[0:31]`.

Но и это не всё. Остаток нужно брать уже после всех вычислений. И константы лучше вычислять, а не жёстко забивать в код в данном случае. Т.е. код должен выглядеть так (на примере одного из алфавитов):

```
print(eng_lower_alphabet[(ord(i) - ord(eng_lower_alphabet[0]) + offset) % len(eng_lower_alphabet)])
```

В принципе, можно вынести этот код в отдельную функцию и потом применять эту функцию сколько нужно раз с нужными аргументами.

Comment: не могли бы вы помочь?
В контексте последней нашей беседы, про опен-сорс проекты.
В общем нашел вот такое https://www.firsttimersonly.com/
Это для совсем новичков.
Там есть такое https://goodfirstissues.com/
И я вот не пойму, по каким критериям проводить поиск "легких" для конкретно меня вопросов. Хочу я допустим найти что-то типа "сортировка" или "работа со строками" или что-то такое же простое.

В общем, если вам интересен опен-сорс, и вы поразбираетесь там, и подскажете, буду вам признателен.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev Я посмотрю, но пока мне разбираться особо некогда, честно говоря.

Answer (score 1):

**Для** `rus_lower_alphabet`

```
if (rus_lower_alphabet.index(i) + (offset % 32)) <= 31:
  print(rus_lower_alphabet[(rus_lower_alphabet.index(i) + (offset % 32))])
else:
  print(rus_lower_alphabet[32 - (rus_lower_alphabet.index(i) + (offset % 32))])
```

**Или**

```
print(rus_lower_alphabet[(rus_lower_alphabet.index(i) + (offset % 32)) % 32])
```